# No window title bar when X Toolkit "-title" argument ends in "lock"

Tags: x11, window-title

I'm seeing an odd X behavior, and am trying to determine whether it's originating in the X Toolkit or in my window manager (fvwm).  I also can't tell whether it's a bug, or inexplicably intended behavior, or some weird side effect caused by an X resource or other configuration option.  So I'd like to know whether people using other X window managers and configurations are seeing the same behavior.

When I start a program from the command line specifying the X Toolkit `-title` option, the argument to that option is typically used as the window title, which is displayed in the title bar.  (Two common applications where I might supply this option are `xterm` and `emacs`.)

What I've found is that when the string I pass to the `-title` option ends in `lock`, the window is instead displayed without a title bar at all.  It doesn't matter what, or how many, characters come before `lock`, only that those four characters be the end of the argument.

That is, the following titles work as expected:

```
-title test
-title locker
-title lock.
-title lock_master
-title lok
-title ock
-title wock
```

while the following titles unexpectedly cause the window to be created without any title bar:

```
-title lock
-title flock
-title wtf_is_going_on_with_lock
```

Does the same thing happen on your system?  What's your environment?  I'm running X.Org X Server 1.16.4 and fvwm 2.6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of a title bar is made by the window manager. For fvwm you probably have a config line (in `~/.fvwm2rc` or similar) like:

```
Style "*lock" NoTitle, NoHandles, BorderWidth 0
```

Then any window with a title ending "lock" will match and have no title bar, etc. This entry was probably intended to match the various X11 clocks: oclock, xclock, ...

Comment: That's exactly it!  The line, from my .fvwm2rc cobbled together over the years and mostly cribbed from others' .fvwm2rc files, is `Style "*lock" NoTitle, NoHandles, Sticky, WindowListSkip, ClickToFocus`